# Create a new column which looks-up values in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,0,1,1,1),
                 b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                 c=c("a","b","c","x","y","z"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

df

#>   a b c
#> 1 0 1 a
#> 2 0 2 b
#> 3 0 3 c
#> 4 1 1 x
#> 5 1 2 y
#> 6 1 3 z
```

I'd like to create a 4th column, "d" which returns the value from "c" where "a" = 0 and b=b, like so:

```
#>   a b c d
#> 1 0 1 a a
#> 2 0 2 b b
#> 3 0 3 c c
#> 4 1 1 x a
#> 5 1 2 y b
#> 6 1 3 z c
```

I've tried:

```
df %>% mutate(d = c[a==0 & b==b])
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I create column "d" using dplyr?

Comment: Is `b == b` a typo?

Comment: `b = b` will always be `TRUE`, so you can take that condition out if that is the case. Also you said `b = b & a = 0`, but in your example, you still provide values for column `d` where `a != 0`. Can you explain this further?

Comment: So for row #4, I want to return the value from "c" where a==0 and b==1 ("a"). For row #5, I want to return the value from "c" where a==0 and b==2 ("b"). And for row #6, I want to return the value from "c" where a==0 and b==3 ("c").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `dplyr` solution:

```
df1 <-  df[df$a == 0,-1]
inner_join(df, df1, by = "b")

#   a b c.x c.y
# 1 0 1   a   a
# 2 0 2   b   b
# 3 0 3   c   c
# 4 1 1   x   a
# 5 1 2   y   b
# 6 1 3   z   c
```

Comment: A base R variation on this being `merge(df, df[df$a == 0, c("b","c")], by="b")` or with renaming `merge(df, transform(df[df$a==0,], d=c)[c("b","d")], by="b")`

Answer (score 2):

Ony `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(d = ifelse(a == 0, c, NA_character_)) %>%
 group_by(b) %>%
 fill(d)

      a     b c     d    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     0     1 a     a    
2     1     1 x     a    
3     0     2 b     b    
4     1     2 y     b    
5     0     3 c     c    
6     1     3 z     c
```

You can also arrange it:

```
df %>%
 mutate(d = ifelse(a == 0, c, NA_character_)) %>%
 group_by(b) %>%
 fill(d) %>%
 arrange(a, b, c)

      a     b c     d    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     0     1 a     a    
2     0     2 b     b    
3     0     3 c     c    
4     1     1 x     a    
5     1     2 y     b    
6     1     3 z     c
```

To cope with scenarios mentioned by @divibisan, you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(d = ifelse(a == 0, c, NA_character_)) %>%
 group_by(b) %>%
 fill(d, .direction = "up") %>%
 fill(d, .direction = "down") %>%
 arrange(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Clever solution! One issue is that for `fill` to behave correctly, the non-NA row (where `a ==0`) must come first (try doing it on `df2 <- df[6:1,]`).

Comment: Thanks - but for some reason column d output is numeric where a=1, b=2 and c=3. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Rez99 Because column `c` is actually a factor, not a character. You can fix it with `as.character`, or use the `stringsAsFactor=F` argument when making the data frame

Comment: @divibisan updated the post, thank you for noticing it :)

Answer (score 2):

With base R you can do the following.

```
inx <- match(df$b, df$b[df$a == 0])
df$d <- df$c[inx]

df
#  a b c d
#1 0 1 a a
#2 0 2 b b
#3 0 3 c c
#4 1 1 x a
#5 1 2 y b
#6 1 3 z c
```